# Cannot get UISearchBar Scope Bar to appear in Toolbar (or anywhere) on iPad

Tags: ipad, scope, uisearchbar, uitoolbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

This is really causing me fits. I see a lot of info on putting a UISearchBar in the top row of a UITableView -- but I am putting the UISearchBar into the Toolbar at the top of my screen (on the iPad).  I cannot find ANYTHING regarding how to handle `UISearchBar` and `UISearchDisplayController` using a `UIPopoverController` on the iPad. Any more info about the `UISearchDisplayController` using a `UIPopoverController` would be greatly appreciated.  Please help with this as I am at my wit's end.

Using IB, I put a toolbar on the IUView on the iPad. I added the following: `Search Bar` (*not* `Search Bar and Search Display`) to the toolbar.  I set the options to be as follows:  Show Cancel Button, Show Scope Bar, Scope Button Titles are: "Title1" and "Title2" (with Title2's radio button selected).  Opaque, Clear Context and Auto Resize are checked.  I hooked up the delegate of `Search Bar` to the "File's Owner" and linked it to IBOutlet `theSearchBar`.

In my `viewWillAppear` I have the following:

```
    //Just in case:
    [theSearchBar setScopeButtonTitles:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Near Me",@"Everywhere",nil]];
    //Just in case (again):
    [theSearchBar setShowsScopeBar:YES];
    //doesn't seem to do anything:
    //[theSearchBar sizeToFit]; 

    searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:theSearchBar contentsController:self];
    [self setSearchDisplayController:searchDisplayController];
    [searchDisplayController setDelegate:self];
    [searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDataSource:self];
    //again--does not seem to do anything..but people have suggested it:
    [theSearchBar sizeToFit];
```

Okay, so far, I thought, so good.  So, I made the File's Owner `.m` file to be a delegate for: `UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate`.

My issue:  I have yet to implement the delegates necessary to do the search but still... shouldn't I be seeing the `scopeBar` next to the search field when I click into the search field?  Just so you know I DO see the log of the characters I type, so the delegate *is* working.

Here is a routine I used to check to see if IB really put the Scope Bar (UISegementedControl) in the searchbar:

```
for (UIView *v in theSearchBar.subviews) 
{
    if ([v isMemberOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]]) 
    {             
        // You've got the segmented control!                 
        UISegmentedControl *scope = (UISegmentedControl *)v;
        // Do your thing here...
        NSLog(@"Found Scope: '%@'\n",scope);
        NSLog(@"Scope Segments: '%d'\n",[v numberOfSegments]);
    }
}
```

This shows:

```
[30013:207] Found Scope: '<UISegmentedControl: 0x68a06b0; frame = (0 0; 200 44); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x68a0600>>'
[30013:207] Scope Segments: '2'
```

So, I know the 2 segments are there.  I also know they are not showing up... 
What am i doing wrong?

Why doesn't the Scope Bar appear?  A results UIPopoverController appears with the title "Results" and "No results found" (of course) when i type the first character in my search...but no scope bar.  (not that i expect anything other than "No Results Found".

I *am* wondering where the scope bar is supposed to appear...in the titleView of the UIPopover?  In the toolbar to the right of the search area?  Where?

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.searchDisplayController searchBar] setScopeButtonTitles:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Near Me",@"Everywhere",nil]];
```

This Might Help.

Answer (score 0):

UISearchBar does not display it's scope when embedded in a UIToolbar, this is true even in iOS 7.

You must build your own UISegment and add it into the table view of the search results or build your own view to hold the UISearchBar that would display scope.